# PHP GMP: POW, exp has to be a float

Tags: php, gmp

Trying to calculate some very large numbers, using the PHP GMP module. Everything worked so far very fine, until i had to use GMP_POW, but the EXP has to be a float, instead of a number or string.

The easy way, which is working for small numbers:

```
$result = pow(25323532325, 0.95); // Output: 7644482136.6877
```

But with GMP:

```
$result = gmp_pow(25323532325, "0.95"); // Output: 1
```

My not so clever idea:

```
$result = gmp_pow(gmp_init(25323532325), gmp_init(0.95)); // Error: Unable to convert variable to GMP - string is not an integer
```

Comment: Since i know that, i am looking for an alternative solution. You are just literally telling, what i figured in my question.

Comment: Please read my comment above, to understand the situation here.

Comment: gmp is mpz_t in the GMP integer library. What you are looking for is the MPFR and I don't see that is is ported.